Fermi momentum vs. nucleon-nucleon momentum
Are there differences between the terms 'Fermi momentum' and 'nucleon-nucleon momentum' and if so, what are they?
I have stumbled across inconsistent terminology in the literature. Some books call the internal momenta of atoms 'Fermi momenta', others call them 'nucleon-nucleon momenta', and these terms are often used interchangeably.
However, I think that this is not accurate. The Fermi momentum describes the momentum that is associated with the Fermi energy, which is the energy of the highest bound state in a system that obeys Fermi statistics - more specifically, $p_F=\sqrt{2mE_F}$. Nucleon-nucleon momenta, as the name suggests, should generally describe the momenta between nucleons, which can originate from Fermi statistics, but also from strong and electroweak interactions.
For the deuteron, one has to be really careful with the wording: One could say the proton and neutron inside the deuteron do not inherit any Fermi momentum, as they are different particles, therefore the Pauli exclusion principle does not apply and both can exist in the lowest energy level. Or, if one is really pedantic, one could say they do inherit Fermi momentum, albeit both of them are simply in the lowest energy level and 'do not stack' the way identical Fermions do.
(Side note: I am trying to model the internal momenta inside the deuteron and need to figure out which 'Fermi momentum distribution' or 'nucleon-nucleon momentum distribution' suits best.)

what makes you think protons and neutrons are different? The are approximately the same, and obey Fermi statistics. This is why deuterons exists, while di-neutrons and $^2$He do not. $pp$, $nn$ and $pn+np$ are unbound, while $pn-np$ is bound. Note that the former are symmetric under particle interchange, while the latter is antisymmetric.

The fact that proton and neutron are different makes me think they are different. Maybe I am not fully understanding Fermi statistics: the Pauli exclusion principle states that a single quantum state can only be occupied by a single fermion. That implies that, when we consider a single fermion type A, the lowest energy state in a system can only be occupied with a fermion of type A with spin up and another one with spin down. However, if we now introduce a second fermion of type B, it has different quantum numbers than type A, so it should also be able to occupy the ground state. Correct?

PEP is correct, but why is a deuteron spin 1? The orbital function,  mostly $S$ and some $D$-wave, is even under exchange. The spin ($S=1$) is triplet, also symmetric under interchange. The nucleon is an isospin $\tau=\frac 1 2$ with two quantum states labeled by quantum number $\tau_3 = \pm \frac 1 2$ corresponding $|p\rangle$ and $|n\rangle$. The PEP means it's iso-spin singlet $|pn\rangle-|np\rangle$, which is antisymmetric, $\tau=0$. If it were spin-0, it would be $\tau=1$, and the other triplet states, $|pp\rangle$ ($^2$He) and $|nn\rangle$ (di-neutron) would exist.
